# How does Serpi protect from web crawling restrictions

Tags: web-crawlers, legal, copyright

I'm thinking of making a website to find the lowest price of an item on the net. The problem is that in the [terms of use of Google search API](https://developers.google.com/terms/#e_prohibitions_on_content) it says that it is forbidden to:

```
Scrape, build databases, or otherwise create permanent copies of such content, or keep
cached copies longer than permitted by the cache header;
```

But somehow [SerpAPI](https://serpapi.com/faq/general/what-are-scraper-legal-protections/) circumvents that? Is that legal? How does that work?

Comment: How are you hoping to use the Google Search API for this?  It seems like you could just crawl a bunch of shopping sites without involving Google at all.

Comment: ummm different sites have different copy right restrictions. I don't know if I can just take the information listed in their site. However, I'm wondering if I using this service is fine for such a purpose